Agregação em C: membro de uma struct declarado como ponteiro para outro struct ou void pointer?
Para exemplificar, considere o código abaixo:
typedef struct dados_s
{
    char *nome;
    int idade;
} dados_t;

typedef struct node_s
{
    dados_t *data;
    struct node_s *next;
} node_t;


node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(dados_t));

// Acessando o "data" da struct
new_node->data->idade = 30;
new_node->data->nome = "Fulano";

Se a declaração da struct node_s fosse alterada para:
typedef struct node_s
{
    void *data;
    struct node_s *next;
} node_t;

Teríamos a declaração e acesso da seguinte forma:
node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(dados_t));
    
((dados_t*)(new_node->data))->idade = 30;
((dados_t*)(new_node->data))->nome = "Fulano";

Como as duas formas funcionam (o que é diferente de estar certo), a segunda forma deve sempre ser evitada ou há pelo menos algum caso que é essencial usar a essa abordagem?

Se vc quer que node_t seja genérico e funcione com qualquer tipo de dados (não se restringindo a dados_t), aí faz mais sentido usar void *. Mas se vc quer que ele aceite apenas dados_t, aí deveria usar este tipo específico. Ou seja, analise caso a caso e use o que fizer mais sentido, de acordo com o que vc precisa. Ver também: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1025579

Vamos lá...
Agregação é quando você recebe um objeto "de fora" em tempo de execução.
No exemplo que você colocou não há agregação, mas composição, pois não há sentido em existir um nó sem dados. Então você deve criar o nó e, ao mesmo tempo, criar os dados do nó. Na verdade, faria mais sentido ter o campo dados_t dado; diretamente na struct e nem precisar de ponteiro algum.
PS: O mais interessante é que o nó é composição, mas a lista ligada é uma agregação...
Para uma lista mais genérica te convido a olhar o código da lista do kernel linux: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h
Se procurar vais encontrar uma versão própria para usuários.
Voltando...
Para fazer agregação, o importante é que o dado venha "de fora", ou seja, você deve usar apontadores (ponteiros) para este novo dado. Realmente não faz muita diferença se você usar void * ou struct dados * para um ou para outro. A segunda forma fica mais "orientado a objetos", e o compilador te dá uma ajuda danada na validação do tipo, então deve ser a preferida.
Só tome cuidado com algumas coisas:

a convenção tipo_t é reservada para a libc e cia e não deve ser usada pelos usuários "normais". A minha convenção é bem OO: os tipos tem a inicial maiúscula seguindo CamelCase e as variáveis com nomes em minúsculo, seguindo snake_case.

o uso de typedef's é para esconder o tipo original; você precisa ter consciência de quando fazer isso e de quando evitar; use typedef's somente quando o encapsulamento for realmente fundamental, caso contrário, não use.

jamais esconda o * quando a variável for do tipo ponteiro!

sempre que possível, deixe cada "classe" em seu classe.c e a interface da "classe" em um classe.h. Tudo separado.

sempre que possível trate todas as structs como "caixa preta", ou seja, não acesse diretamente os campos, de fora do teu classe.c a menos que seja absolutamente necessário.

E, sempre que possível, use alocação no stack e não no heap. Se usar alocação dinâmica via heap, deixe que o usuário faça o malloc (podes até prover uma função que ajude na alocação dinâmica via heap, se desejar), para isso a inicialização deve ser feita após a alocação por uma função própria para isso, aí você ganha os dois tipos de alocação (stack e heap) - obviamente que, para isso, você não pode usar tipos incompletos).


É isso.
